# Is it possible to open a natively installed os in qemu/kvm without passing the whole disk to the vm?

Tags: dual-boot, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I dual-boot linux and windows. I want to be able to open my native installation of windows as a vm so I don't have to leave linux to do things such as updating windows.

The way I have found to make it work is to pass my whole disks(/dev/sda,/dev/sdb..., each disk has both windows and linux partitions) to the virtual machine. This works fine when I open windows because my windows and linux partitions are completely separate(I don't mount any windows partitions in my linux install). The downside of passing the whole disk to the vm is that you can also open (by mistake) your linux install that is running, which I am sure will wreak havoc on my system.

So, is there any alternative to the way I do it now?

Comment: EchoMike is unto something. You *may* be able to use a loop device to create a block device which only includes the partitions you want to expose. The problem is that you also need to expose the beginning of the disks since that's where the partition tables are stored. Which means that even if the Linux partitions cannot be seen by Windows the partition table will show they exist; There will be a discrepancy between what the partition table says and the size of the disk (since it's truncated by the loop device). How the OSes will respond to that I can only speculate.

Comment: How would you accidentally open the Linux partitions? Windows itself doesn't know how to work with Ext4 and the like.

Comment: @multithr3at3d What I mean by accidentally opening the Linux partitions is selecting to boot into linux at the bootloader instead of windows by mistake

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a loop device , with --sizelimit option .

```
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda
146774507520
# losetup  -f  --sizelimit $(( 200*1024*1024 )) /dev/zero
/dev/loop0
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
209715200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply pass through the partitions you need. So, let's assume your Windows install is on partition 1 of disk `sda`. Instead of specifying `/dev/sda` in KVM/QEMU config, replace with `/dev/sda1`, and repeat for any other partitions as separate disks.